# The knack to reduce the amount of calculations for the value of the determinant of $~5\times 5~$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\det\left(A\right):=
\begin{vmatrix}
3&4&6&3&-1\\
2&1&-3&2&2\\
-2&3&2&1&-3\\
1&1&1&3&-1\\
2&-1&5&-3&6\\
\end{vmatrix}=848
$$

To simplify the calcuations, I attempted to find some regularity from the given determinant.

$$~\text{sum of each element of 1st row above}~=~15$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 2nd row above}~=~4$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 3rd row above}~=~1$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 4th row above}~=~5$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 5th row above}~=~9$$

No such regularity couldn't be found about rows.

$$~\text{sum of each element of 1st column above}~=~6$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 2nd column above}~=~8$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 3rd column above}~=~11$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 4th column above}~=~6$$

$$~\text{sum of each element of 5th column above}~=~3$$

Same with the columns.

The following way is what I done to derive the value of the deterrminant with greedy way.

$$\det\left(A\right):=
\begin{vmatrix}
3&4&6&3&-1\\
2&1&-3&2&2\\
-2&3&2&1&-3\\
1&1&1&3&-1\\
2&-1&5&-3&6\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$$=
\begin{vmatrix}
1&3&9&1&-3\\
2&1&-3&2&2\\
-2&3&2&1&-3\\
1&1&1&3&-1\\
2&-1&5&-3&6\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Substracted row2from row1} 
$$

$$=
\begin{vmatrix}
3&0&7&0&0\\
2&1&-3&2&2\\
-2&3&2&1&-3\\
1&1&1&3&-1\\
2&-1&5&-3&6\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Substracted row3from row1} 
$$

$$=
\begin{vmatrix}
2&-1&6&-3&1\\
2&1&-3&2&2\\
-2&3&2&1&-3\\
1&1&1&3&-1\\
2&-1&5&-3&6\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Substracted row4from row1} 
$$

$$=
\begin{vmatrix}
0&0&1&0&-5\\
2&1&-3&2&2\\
-2&3&2&1&-3\\
1&1&1&3&-1\\
2&-1&5&-3&6\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Substracted row5from row1} 
$$

$$=
\begin{vmatrix}
0&0&1&0&0\\
2&1&-3&2&-13\\
-2&3&2&1&7\\
1&1&1&3&4\\
2&-1&5&-3&31\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Added}~~\text{column}_{3}*5~~\text{to}~~\text{column}_{5} 
$$

$$=\left(-1\right)^{\left(1+3\right)}\cdot\left(1\right)\cdot 
\begin{vmatrix}
2&1&2&-13\\
-2&3&1&7\\
1&1&3&4\\
2&-1&-3&31\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Cofactor expansion.} 
$$

$$= 
\begin{vmatrix}
2&1&2&-13\\
-2&3&1&7\\
1&1&3&4\\
2&-1&-3&31\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$$=\left(-1\right) 
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&3&4\\
-2&3&1&7\\
2&1&2&-13\\
2&-1&-3&31\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Switched row1and row3} 
$$

$$=\left(-1\right) 
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&3&4\\
0&5&7&15\\
0&-1&-4&-21\\
0&-3&-9&23\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Made 3zeros from(1,1)th elem} 
$$

$$=\left(-1\right) 
\begin{vmatrix}
5&7&15\\
-1&-4&-21\\
-3&-9&23\\
\end{vmatrix}~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Cofactor expansion.} 
$$

$$=\left(-1\right)\cdot\left(-1\right) 
\begin{vmatrix}
5&7&15\\
1&4&21\\
-3&-9&23\\
\end{vmatrix}~~
$$

$$= 
\begin{vmatrix}
5&7&15\\
1&4&21\\
-3&-9&23\\
\end{vmatrix}=848
$$

Comment: The standard way to calculate a determinant is by using row/column operations—that's much faster than using the definition.

Comment: Subtracting one row from the others you can make it upper or lower triangular matrix and then calculate the determinant easily

Comment: For a shortcut, subtracting rows 2 and 3 from the first row gives you 3 zeros there. Adding the last two rows gives 2 more zeros.

Comment: @dxiv I will try your way first.